# Are there any reliable jqmobile or other touch events for phonegap apps?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, touch-event

I've tried everything, but no single type of touch event works across the entire app. The 'click' seems to be the best fit so far, but every time I come across a button that doesn't trigger a click event, and change it to some touch event, some other part of the app that worked before stops working.

I've tried everything from vclick, tap, touchend and nothing works all the way across, any suggestions? I've been thinking about building a custom tap event, but I don't know how long that would take.

Comment: Take a look at this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/my-first-phonegap-jquerymobile-android-app-done